# Cordova + Sencha Touch: Delete file after it has been used

Tags: database, file, cordova, sencha-touch, delete-file

So I'm using Cordova + Sencha Touch for an app and Antair's SQLitePlugin (https://github.com/Antair/Cordova-SQLitePlugin) to import and use an SQLite database in it.

I managed to import my (kinda big) prepopulated database using Antair's importPrepopulatedDatabase ( `window.sqlitePlugin.importPrepopulatedDatabase({file:"mydb.db",importIfExists:false})` ) method and it works just fine. The thing is I noticed the app is using twice the size it really needs as it keeps the file after importing it.

I checked and the app works just fine if I delete the file from /cordova/www/db and build again, it keeps the actual db in the app's filesystem I guess, but I can't find a way to programmatically delete that file after it has been imported.

I looked around and found cordova file plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md), but from what I saw from the docs it only grants read permissions on the www folder, so that won't do it.

Does anyone have any workaround for this? I could really use that extra space.

Answer (score 1):

By using cordova file plugin api you can do this,

please refer this :

```
       deleteFile: function(fileName) {

    var that = this;

    if (!fileName) {
        console.error("No fileName specified. File could not be deleted.");
        return false;
    }

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, function(fileSystem){ // this returns the tmp folder 

        // File found
        fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, {create: false}, function(fileEntry){
            fileEntry.remove(function(success){
                console.log(success);
            }, function(error){
                console.error("deletion failed: " + error);
            });
        }, that.get('fail'));
    }, this.get('fail'));

}
```

Comment: would that give me access to the app's data or just common phone data (like photo roll or documents)? Also I haven't tried this yet buy TEMPORARY doesn't seem like the name (or property) of the folder in which my file is.

Comment: it will give you access to your app data. where are you storing data? inside application storage?

Comment: I'm shipping my app with a db file in cordova's www folder. I suppose that's app storage yeah